# Installing npm on vagrant

Tags: npm, vagrant, npm-install

I tried to install and use npm in two ways, but I get only errors.

Installing npm by normal way:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ npm install
npm ERR! Couldn't read dependencies.

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/vagrant/package.json'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/vagrant/package.json'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Trying to install latest version:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ npm install -g npm@latest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: npm
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm@latest"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

What should I install before to create this package.json file ane make it work?

Comment: npm seems to already be installed. The first error is due to missing package.json file. What npm version do you have (`npm -v`)?

Answer (score 0):

npm looks like it's already installed. Go to your project root and:

```
npm init
```

It'll walk you through making a package.json file, then you can

```
npm i whateverpackageyouwant
```

to your heart's content.

Comment: I tried that. When I try to install something I get same error.npm          http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: bower
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> 
/*  */
npm not ok

Comment: Can you do me a favor and `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and then `npm i grunt-bower-concat --save-dev` for me in a new project folder, then put the output in your question?

Comment: At first I pasted debug log file and then everything i wrote in GitBash. http://pastebin.com/CPqVWbAK  Thank you very much for your help.